# Apply FUN row-wise on data frame with integer and character variables

Tags: r, function, dataframe, row, apply

A completely basic question - and forgive me if it is a duplicate.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- 
  data.frame(id=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'),
             a=sample(1:10, size=5, replace=T),
             b=sample(1:10, size=5, replace=T),
             c=sample(1:10, size=5, replace=T))
```

Then,

```
> df
  id  a  b c
1  a  3  9 3
2  a  4 10 2
3  b  6  7 7
4  b 10  7 4
5  a  3  1 8
```

To return the column name (a, b or c) with the largest value, and if this is in the `id` variable take the second highest, I use the below function.

```
FUN <- function(r) {
  top <- names(r[,c('a', 'b', 'c')])[order(r[,c('a', 'b', 'c')], decreasing=T)]
  ifelse(top[1] == r[['id']], top[2], top[1])
}
```

I can do:

```
FUN(df[1,]) #[1] "b"
```

and for all rows:

```
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
res <- c(res, FUN(df[i,]))  
}
```

And get

```
> res
[1] "b" "b" "c" "a" "c"
```

But how can I `apply` this ? E.g. this is not working:

```
apply(df, 1, FUN)
```

I suspect the trouble is that `FUN` assumes a 1-row data frame (and not a named vector of characters like (first row))

```
 id   a   b   c 
"a" "3" "9" "c"
```

From `apply?`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

Comment: Do you have to use that function? Or are you looking for a way to get the max columns?

Comment: I am trying to understand how, in general, to do something row-wise using a function that expect a dataframe row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use your function, you can do,

```
sapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), f1)
#  1   2   3   4   5 
#"b" "b" "c" "a" "c"
```

**NOTE** I renamed your `FUN` to `f1` since `FUN` is used by various functions in R so as to define the argument of function

Comment: Ah exactly!. You use `split` to get a list by row that can then be fed into `lapply`. Great, and very general.

Comment: I used `sapply` here to get a vector but you can use `lapply` too If you want the results to be in a list

Comment: Sure sure `sapply` is what I want (as in  `lapply(x, f1, simplify=F, USE.NAMES=F)` )

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make some minor modifications to your `FUN`. I think the issue you were running into was that `apply` will treat each row as a vector. Since your `id` column is a character, this means that your `a/b/c` columns will also be coerced to character. Realizing this we can modify the `FUN` slightly to convert it back to `numeric` for ordering:

```
FUN <- function(r) {
  top <- c('a', 'b', 'c')[order(as.numeric(r[c('a', 'b', 'c')]), decreasing=T)]
  ifelse(top[1] == as.character(r['id']), top[2], top[1])
}

apply(df, 1, FUN)
#[1] "b" "b" "c" "a" "c"
```

To see how this works in a little more detail you can run the below and see that `apply` is reading through named character vectors.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {print(x); print(class(x)); return(NULL)})
#  id    a    b    c 
# "a" " 3" " 9"  "3" 
#[1] "character"
#  id    a    b    c 
# "a" " 4" "10"  "2" 
#[1] "character"
#  id    a    b    c 
# "b" " 6" " 7"  "7" 
#[1] "character"
#  id    a    b    c 
# "b" "10" " 7"  "4" 
#[1] "character"
#  id    a    b    c 
# "a" " 3" " 1"  "8" 
#[1] "character"
#NULL
```

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that but wanted to avoid the `as.numeric` and `as.character` .

Comment: I included the `as.character` because I didn't know if `r["id"]` was a factor or not.