# Creating a new column in R that uses an equation referencing other columns

Tags: r, equation

Hi I am trying to create a new column called "pCO2" in my data set called "Erie". My dataset currently has ph, alk, and temp values. there is a package called AquaEnv that lets you predict the CO2 value if you have the pH and alkalinity value.

This is the equation to find the values I want in the "pCO2 column"

```
ae<-aquaenv(S=0,t=0,p=0, SumCO2 = NULL, pH= 7.7,TA=90 )
ae$SumCO2
```

Is there a way to do this while referencing the corresponding pH and alkalinity values in my Erie dataset?

this was my idea, but it does not give the correct values.

```
Erie$pCO2<-aquaenv(S=0,t=0,p=0, SumCO2 = NULL, pH=Erie$pH,TA= 
  Erie$ALKALINITY..mg.L.)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly common question, with no real good answer.

Quickest way to get it working is:

```
df$SumCO2 <- sapply(
  split(Erie, 1:nrow(Erie)),
  function(r) {
    return(aquaenv(S=0,t=0,p=0,SumCO2=NULL, pH=r$pH, TA=r$ALKALINITY..mg.L.)$SumCO2)
  }
)
```

To walk it through, this splits the `Erie` data.frame into a set of data.frames (one per row) and for each row invokes this function.

Slightly cleaner is the `mapply` approach:

```
mapply(
  function(pH, TA) {
    return(aquaenv(S=0,t=0,p=0,SumCO2=NULL, pH=pH, TA=TA)$SumCO2)
  }, Erie$pH, Erie$ALKALINITY..mg.L
)
```

Some similar questions with other approaches:

- [Apply FUN row-wise on data frame with integer and character variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591238/)
- [Call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/)